# How to attach a variable number of attachments?

Tags: vba, outlook

The below code is an auto email sender. It works only if there are attachments.

Some emails have 1 or more attachments. If the path is blank it will not work.

Each email has a variable number of attachments and some paths is empty. Is there any way to make the pdfadd1 to pdfadd5 ignore adding attachment if the path is empty?

```vb
Sub send_mass_email_display_only()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name As String, email As String, body As String, subject As String, copy As String, pdfadd1 As String, pdfadd2 As String, pdfadd3 As String, pdfadd4 As String, pdfadd5 As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    For i = 2 To 3
        'Specific rows
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0)
        'name = Cells(i, 1).Value
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        pdfadd1 = Cells(i, 5).Value
        pdfadd2 = Cells(i, 6).Value
        'pdfadd3 = Cells(i, 7).Value
        'pdfadd4 = Cells(i, 8).Value
        'pdfadd5 = Cells(i, 9).Value
        
        body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
        
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
             .SentOnBehalfOfName = Cells(7, 17).Value
             .To = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .body = body
             .Attachments.Add (pdfadd1)
             .Attachments.Add (pdfadd2)
             '.Attachments.Add (pdfadd3)
             '.Attachments.Add (pdfadd4)
             '.Attachments.Add (pdfadd5)
             .display
             '.Send
        End With
    
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
        
    Next i
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    'MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Len(pdfadd1) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add (pdfadd1)`

Comment: @brax thank for the quick reply, may I ask how to structure it please, I added it below body but it has an error            
  .body = body
             If Len(pdfadd1) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add (pdfadd1)

Comment: You already have a similar line (without the IF part) - replace it with what i posted. Do that for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant part. I just added an `If` statement to each one to make sure the length is greater than zero.

```
 .body = body
 If Len(pdfadd1) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add pdfadd1
 If Len(pdfadd2) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add pdfadd2
 If Len(pdfadd3) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add pdfadd3
 If Len(pdfadd4) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add pdfadd4
 If Len(pdfadd5) > 0 Then .Attachments.Add pdfadd5
 .display
```

<sub>Also, you do not need the parenthesis around the argument for `.Add` in this case as it's not returning anything.</sub>